# No preview available on the Webview

Tags: android, firebase, webview, android-webview

I have an App in which I want to display PDF files in a webview. I have managed to get the code up and running, but the problem is when I try to run my App, it displays this "no preview available" to me. 
I am thinking the problem is with my PDF URL from firebase. Because another PDF URL loads just fine.
Does anyone know what's wrong? And how can I fix this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open local pdf file in WebView Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49226127/how-to-open-local-pdf-file-in-webview-android-studio)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I just tried it myself, the problem is that with firebase the PDF gets downloaded rather than display by webview. Try storeing the PDF in the drive an use its url for webview. Hope it works.

Comment: Did this help you